# VB.NET Arithmetic operation caused an overflow

Tags: vb.net, math

I have a function that changes the brightness of an image.

However I am getting the error "Arithmetic operation caused an overflow. You may not divide by 0.". in the line

```
bData.ByteData(ii) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii) + (amount * (255 - bData.ByteData(ii)))) 'blue
```

"amount" is 30.

I am not sure what I did wrong. Does anybody see my error? 
Thank you!

```
    Public Sub Brightness(Optional ByVal amount As Single = 0)
        OnFilterStarted()
        If amount = 0 Then Return
        Dim bData = BitmapData.LockBits(b)
        If amount > 0 Then
            For ii = bData.ByteData.GetLowerBound(0) To bData.ByteData.GetUpperBound(0) Step 4
                bData.ByteData(ii) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii) + (amount * (255 - bData.ByteData(ii)))) 'blue
                bData.ByteData(ii + 1) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii + 1) + (amount * (255 - bData.ByteData(ii + 1)))) 'green
                bData.ByteData(ii + 2) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii + 2) + (amount * (255 - bData.ByteData(ii + 2)))) 'red
            Next
        Else
            For ii = bData.ByteData.GetLowerBound(0) To bData.ByteData.GetUpperBound(0) Step 4
                bData.ByteData(ii) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii) - (Math.Abs(amount) * bData.ByteData(ii))) 'blue
                bData.ByteData(ii + 1) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii + 1) - (Math.Abs(amount) * bData.ByteData(ii + 1))) 'green
                bData.ByteData(ii + 2) = CByte(bData.ByteData(ii + 2) - (Math.Abs(amount) * bData.ByteData(ii + 2))) 'red
            Next
        End If
        bData.UnlockBits()
        OnFilterFinished()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the value of ByteData(ii) when this happens. I'm pretty sure the result goes beyond the boundary of a byte. If you multiply by 30, you aren't giving yourself a lot of space. You're overflow isn't caused by a divide.

Comment: @the_lotus Indeed. The only valid value for the input byte that WON'T cause an overflow is 255.

Comment: Refactoring the code will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us the value of ByteData(ii) when this happens. I'm pretty sure the result goes beyond the boundary of a byte. If you multiply by 30, you aren't giving yourself a lot of space. You're overflow isn't caused by a divide.

Example, this will cause the error.

```
    Dim b As Byte
    Dim a As Single

    b = 128
    a = 30

    b += a * (255 - b)
```

The only way for it to not cause an error is if b is equal to 255 (thanks mafafu).